# Error in Ruby Exception class documentation?

Tags: ruby

Regarding the **class method** `Exception.exception`, the official documentation (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Exception.html#method-c-exception) says:

> With no argument, or if the argument is the same as the receiver,
>   return the receiver. Otherwise, create a new exception object of the
>   same class as the receiver, but with a message equal to string.to_str.

This is true for the instance method of the same name, but not for the class method.

`ExampleError.exception` does NOT return the receiver:

```
class ExampleError < Exception; end

p ExampleError.class            # => Class
p ExampleError.exception.class  # => ExampleError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is confused. The documentation generator is probably getting confused because `Exception` has a class method and an instance method with the same name.

If we have a look at [the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/error.c#L1697), we'll see this:

```
void
Init_Exception(void)
{
    rb_eException   = rb_define_class("Exception", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_singleton_method(rb_eException, "exception", rb_class_new_instance, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_eException, "exception", exc_exception, -1);
    /* ... */
```

This one adds the class method:

```
rb_define_singleton_method(rb_eException, "exception", rb_class_new_instance, -1);
```

and this one adds the instance method:

```
rb_define_method(rb_eException, "exception", exc_exception, -1);
```

If you track down [`exc_exception`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/error.c#L574) you'll see where the documentation comes from. If you track down [`rb_class_new_instance`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/object.c#L1741) you'll see that `rb_class_new_instance` is just the standard `new` method. That means that these do exactly the same thing:

```
Exception.new
Exception.exception
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood both Exception.new and Exception.exception produce the same output, I was just confused that it contradicted the documentation.  Your answer is great.